# Grails struggling with bcrypt

Tags: grails, bcrypt

I've been trying to get this working for half a day now. I am trying to use password encryption in my grails app using the bcrypt plugin by Seymour Cakes and Burt Beckwith:

http://grails.org/plugin/bcrypt

I have put the appropriate dependency in my BuildConfig.groovy and in my controller I am trying to run a simple test:

```
def bcryptService
    String goodpwd = "good"
    String badpwd = "bad"
    String encryptedpwd = goodpwd.encodeAsBcrypt()
    println " "
    println "Good Password: " + goodpwd
    println "Bad Password: " + badpwd
    println "Bcrypt Hash Of Good Password: " + encryptedpwd

    println "Matching good password: " + (goodpwd.encodeAsBcrypt().equals(encryptedpwd))
    println "Matching bad password: " + (badpwd.encodeAsBcrypt().equals(encryptedpwd))
    println "Bcrypt Service's match result: " + bcryptservice.checkPassword(goodpwd, encryptedpwd)
```

but I get this:

```
Good Password: good
Bad Password: bad
Bcrypt Hash Of Good Password: $2a$10$KvQOvmA4QjH4.JEk4.V2/uXYf8UjKJaUccDijQWG3RkBgAA2LOndS
Matching good password: false
Matching bad password: false
Error |
2014-05-21 14:20:05,935 [http-bio-8080-exec-9] ERROR errors.GrailsExceptionResolver  -         MissingPropertyException occurred when processing request: [POST] /FatcaOne_0    
No such property: bcryptservice for class: com.twc.fatcaone.AdminController. Stacktrace     follows:
Message: No such property: bcryptservice for class: com.twc.fatcaone.AdminController
Line | Method
->>   71 | doCall    in com.twc.fatcaone.AdminController$_closure5$$EOevDLMH
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
```

sometimes it does that other times it complains that bcryptService is a null. I don't understand what I am doing wrong to not get this dependency injected. Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: `bcryptservice` should be `bcryptService`. CamelCase

Comment: @dmahapatro I tried that and I get this: `Cannot invoke method checkPassword() on null object. Stacktrace follows:
Message: Cannot invoke method checkPassword() on null object
    Line | Method
->>   71 | doCall    in com.twc.fatcaone.AdminController$_closure5

|    198 | doFilter  in grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.PageFragmentCachingFilter
|     63 | doFilter  in grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.AbstractFilter
|   1145 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run . . . in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker`

Comment: @dmahapatro I have this line in my BuildConfig.groovy `compile ":bcrypt:1.0"` and as far as I can tell I have no dependency errors.

Comment: Did you update this line as well to use camelCase service name? `bcryptservice.checkPassword(goodpwd, encryptedpwd)`

Comment: @dmahapatro, yes that is what I tried. I was already camel casing the definition of bcryptService but in that line you pointed out I wasn't so I have now done it there too. That's when I got the null pointer error.

Comment: @dmahapatro `2014-05-21 15:35:56,364 [http-bio-8080-exec-10] ERROR errors.GrailsExceptionResolver  - NullPointerException occurred when processing request: [POST] /FatcaOne_0/admin/addInstitution` This is the beginining part of that null pointer error I get.

Comment: @dmahapatro Thanks for the edit. Im still a bit of a newbie on formatting questions in SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your first chunk of code is inside a method, then make sure you take the

```
def bcryptService
```

line out of this block of code and place it at the class level in the controller.